# Why does changing the variable name in post request doesn't add the string array to db?, express, mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

To simplify the question, **I have labeled error scenario as Scenario A,** *working scenario as Scenario B*, I would like to know why it does what it does

**Scenario A (error)**

***Step 1***
[image]

***Step 2 & 3***
[image]

**Scenario B (working)**

***Step 1***
[image]

***Step 2 & 3***
[image]

I would like to understand why Scenario A does not add the string of array/users to the database? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this help https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question ?

Comment: Thanks, but i put a lot of effort to label the images sorry about that

Comment: Fair point, I see a lot of effort. Sorry they were put in the wrong place. The simple snippets of working code vs failing would be enough to point you to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment. Putting efforts into reading this page would pay back better than painting screenshots.  You know they say working smarter is better than working harder. By following the guidance you could save this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the JSON structure. When you simply enter a variable into the JSON without a field name, the variable name defaults to the field name.

For example, given `var x = 5`, `{x}` would auto expand to `{x: 5}` while `{y: x}` would expand to `{y: 5}`.

The same logic can be applied to your Cycle object, you're initiating it, in Scenario 1, with `{usersA: usersA}` instead of `{users: usersA}`